# Cannot get input field value in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to pass a value from the input field using knockout, so here is a form

```
<form>
  <input id="amount"  type="text"  placeholder="Amount in &euro;" data-bind="value : amount" />
  <button class="button1" type="submit"  data-bind="click: $root.invest_first_pageview" >Invest</button> 
  <button class="button2" type="submit"  data-bind="click: $root.borrow_first_pageview" >Borrow</button> 
</form>
```

and I am trying to get the value in my knockout js file like this,

```
self.invest_first_pageview = function () {
    alert("HELLO");
    window.location.href = BASEURL + "index.php/moneyexchange/invest_first_page/" + self.amount();
};

// Navigates to the desired URL allowing editing the money specified.
self.borrow_first_pageview = function () {
    window.location.href = BASEURL + "index.php/moneyexchange/borrow_first_page/" + self.amount();
};
```

But it looks like the `self.amount()` is not getting any values.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a full (but minimal) repro, and explain what you mean by "is not getting any values".

Comment: @Jeroen What I meant is that , when I call the function on submit, I Am not getting any value inside self.amount()

Comment: Still unclear to me. What does "not getting any value" mean? Does it equal `null`? Or `undefined`? Or an empty string? Or zero? Or does it throw an error? ... In any case, the code you've currently posted *does not reproduce any of those at all*.

Comment: @Jeroen well I forgot to put a ko observable for amount, so when I clicked the buttons I did not get any values in that observable, so in my alert statement it was null, sorry if it was unclear, but  I got my answer from the below post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as shown in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/jLfy8u43/) if your `amount` observable is in the same scope meaning e.g. there is no `foreach` iteration embracing the snippet you show. You may change `data-bind="value : amount"` to `data-bind="value : $root.amount"`.

Is your model anywhere close too:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.amount = ko.observable();
    self.invest_first_pageview = function() {
        alert(self.amount());
        window.location.href = BASEURL + "index.php/moneyexchange/invest_first_page/" + self.amount();
    };

    // Navigates to the desired URL allowing editing the money specified.
    self.borrow_first_pageview = function() {
        window.location.href = BASEURL + "index.php/moneyexchange/borrow_first_page/" + self.amount();
    };
};
```

Comment: Please don't answer with a *guess* at the OP's problem if the question doesn't contain enough info. Instead, ask the OP in a comment to clarify, and flag to close as off-topic if appropriate.

Comment: @Jeroen hey, this isnt an off topic

Comment: @Nikolay Ermakov, I forgot to put self.amount = ko.observable(); that was my mistake, and thanks!!!